# FFMPEG: using video filter with complex filter

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-processing, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm using the `fluent-ffmpeg` Node.js library to perform batch manipulations on video files. The video filter which crops a 16:9 input, adds padding and burns subtitles into the padding.

In the next step, I would like to use a complex filter to overlay an image as a watermark.

```
ff.input(video.mp4)
ff.input(watermark.png)
ff.videoFilter([
  'crop=in_w-2*150:in_h',
  'pad=980:980:x=0:y=0:color=black',
  'subtitles=subtitles.ass'
])
ff.complexFilter([
  'overlay=0:0'
])
ff.output(output.mp4)
```

However, running this, I get the following error:

```
Filtergraph 'crop=in_w-2*150:in_h,pad=980:980:x=0:y=0:color=black,subtitles=subtitles.ass' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a comple.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

From what I understand the video filter and complex filter options can't be used together. How does one get around this?

Comment: You will have to put the overlay filter in one filter only. You cannot use 2 filtergraphs in ffmpeg in the same command. Try to study the complex filtergraphs and match your stream accordingly to the overlay filter.

Comment: You can use multiple complex filtergraphs in the same command. You just can't refer to intermediate or output streams, created in one graph, in the other graphs.

Answer (score 45):

Solved this by learning some basics about filter graphs. Here's the full ffmpeg command. I find the filter strings easier to read when they are written out line-by-line.

```
ffmpeg \
-i video.mp4 \
-i watermark.png \
-filter_complex " \
  [0]crop = \
    w = in_w-2*150 : \
    h = in_h \
    [a] ;
  [a]pad = \
    width = 980 : \
    height = 980 : \
    x = 0 :
    y = 0 :
    color = black
    [b] ;
  [b]subtitles = 
    filename = subtitles.ass
    [c] ;
  [c][1]overlay = \
    x = 0 :
    y = 0
  " \
output.mp4
```

Explanation:

`[0]crop=...[a];` => Begin by applying crop filter to video input `0`. Name the result `a`.

`[a]pad=...[b];` => Apply the pad filter to the `a` stream. Name the result `b`.

`[b]subtitles=...[c]` => Apply the subtitles filter to the `b` stream. Name the result `c`.

`[c][1]overlay...` => Apply the overlay filter to stream `c` using input `1` (the png file).

Hope this helps someone struggling with filter graphs.

Comment: The filters that have a single input/output can be joined by commas which can simplify the command somewhat because you can omit unnecessary labeling such as `[0]crop,pad[bg];[bg][1]overlay,subtitles` or `[0]crop,pad,subtitles[bg];[bg][1]overlay`.

Comment: Your Q is about fluent-ffmpeg syntax. This answer relates to ffmpeg CLI syntax.

Comment: Yes, but the filter graph was the issue.

Comment: Do you have the fluent-ffmpeg version?

Answer (score 7):

simple syntax with 3 logos and 1 text scroll

```
ffmpeg
    .complexFilter([

        {
            filter: 'overlay',
            options: { x: 100, y: 100 },
            inputs: 0, outputs: '1'

        },
        {
            filter: 'overlay',
            options: { x: 200, y: 200 },
            inputs: '1', outputs: '2'

        },
        {
            filter: 'overlay',
            options: { x: 300, y: 300 },
            inputs: '2', outputs: '3'

        },
        {
            filter: 'drawtext',
            options: {
            // outputs: 1,
            fontfile:'/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf',
            text: 'some text',
            fontsize: 40,
            fontcolor: 'white',
            x: 'w-w/10*mod(t,10*(w+tw)/w)',
            y: 'h-line_h',
            shadowcolor: 'black',
            shadowx: 3,
            shadowy: 3,
            },
            inputs: '3',
          },
        ])
```