# Applying filters on a video in flutter

Tags: flutter

I was wondering if there is a way to apply filters on a video in flutter.
The video can be a screen recording or a filming through the phone's camera.

We already possess the knowledge about image filters, but not for videos.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got the solution for video filter in flutter?

Comment: not yet, will let you know

Comment: left flutter......now

Comment: Hey, did your every get the solution for video filter ?

Answer (score 2):

In my knowledge, there are two packages that you can use, [tapioca](https://pub.dev/packages/tapioca) and [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg)

There is and example for **tapioca** on the link, and for flutter_ffmpeg, you can visit [Video filter in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455922/ffmpeg-using-video-filter-with-complex-filter) to see how video filters are applied in ffmpeg.

NOTE: There is a different way of using ffmpeg command in flutter, so I think you can't directly just copy and paste the commands (given in [Video filter in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455922/ffmpeg-using-video-filter-with-complex-filter)).